# using appadmin for other models than db.py in web2py

Tags: python, web2py

in web2py we I created a new application called imageblog and in models on default I have 2 models :

```
db.py
menu.py
coffee.py   #this is new one created by me in models i made some tables inside this too
```

and if I use the url

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/imageblog/appadmin/
```

I can see the appadmin of the db.py model but my question is I created another model called 
coffee.py how can I open coffee.py in appadmin?
I tried:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/imageblog/coffee/appadmin
```

I get output as : "invalid function (coffee/appadmin)"
but no luck.
Is appadmin only available for db.py ???

==================================================================================

so as I researched a little more and everybody is telling me I should be able to access all the models from appadmin so i think its might be my code is doing something wrong so i am pasting the model in coffee.py:

```
db = DAL("sqlite://storage.sqlite")

db.define_table('cimage',
   Field('title', unique=True),
   Field('file', 'upload'),
   format = '%(title)s')
```

and in appadmin i get the following:

Available Databases and Tables

```
db.auth_user    New Record
db.auth_group   New Record
db.auth_membership  New Record
db.auth_permission  New Record
db.auth_event   New Record
db.auth_cas New Record
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In appadmin, you will be able to access database tables for any model defined in any model file.

**Update** (based on info posted to the web2py user group):

The problem is that you are defining `db = DAL(...)` in both coffee.py and db.py. Because db.py comes after coffee.py, the `db` object defined in coffee.py is simply replaced by the one defined in db.py, so none of the models in coffee.py will be available to any controller, including the appadmin controller.

You should define the `db` object only once, in the first model file that runs (model files run in alphanumeric order).

Comment: i the alpha numeric order was the main reason for all this confusion as i was trying it without defining db in coffee but c comes before d (coffe / db) so it was causing error. Thank you